# $.post() doesn't send data as json but as x-www-form-urlencoded instead

Tags: jquery, post

This one is really weird. I have multiple `$.post()` in the code, but there is one don't know why sends the json parameters as `x-www-form-urlencoded` instead and therefore doesn't work.

Here's the code:

```
$.post("/Route/SaveTransportProperties", { properties: JSON.stringify(propArray), currTravelBox: JSON.stringify(travelBoxObj), accessToken: getAccessToken()}, function(data)
    {
        //DO STUFF
    });
```

The XHR looks like this in Firefox:
[image: Firefox screenshot]

Any ideas why is this happening? I also enforced the type as 'json' but doesn't work either.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you want to send the data as json then use the $.ajax function

You can specify type post and dataType json.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "mydomain.com/url",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "xml/html/script/json", // expected format for response
  contentType: "application/json", // send as JSON
  data: $.param( $("Element or Expression") ),

  complete: function() {
    //called when complete
  },

  success: function() {
    //called when successful
 },

  error: function() {
    //called when there is an error
  },
});
```

Taken from ajax documentation

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
contentTypeString
Default: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
```

Comment: Ok. I migth have miscopied the ajax code from somewhere, or perhaps from an old or newer jquery version but problem why ajax as not working ( see my comment under Olli answer ) was bc in the type param i had "JSON" instead of "POST"

Comment: dataType specifies the expected type of the _response_, not the post data.  The answer by Olli is correct - you need to use $.ajax and specify the contentType option.

Comment: $.param(obj) could be replaced with JSON.stringify(obj) which performs better. See benchmark here: http://jsperf.com/jquery-param-and-json-stringify

Answer (score 9):

Because [$.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) is for sending form-like requests. [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is for sending whatever you want to. See `contentType` in `$.ajax` page for more information.

Quote:

> When sending data to the server, use this content-type. Default is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", which is fine for most cases. If you explicitly pass in a content-type to $.ajax() then it'll always be sent to the server (even if no data is sent). Data will always be transmitted to the server using UTF-8 charset; you must decode this appropriately on the server side.

Comment: Post is a shorthand for $.ajax() so it should work and also i've it working in other place inside my code.... its just here that it seems to fail. Reason why i'm not using $.ajax() its because in IE9 compat mode is throwing an exception "SCRIPT87: Invalid argument." but with $.post() ( besides its not working...that shy my question) doesn't throw any error.

Answer (score 6):

this also works for me

```
$.ajax({
  url: "mydomain.com/url",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "xml/html/script/json", // expected format for response
  contentType: "application/json", // send as JSON
  data: JSON.stringify(data),

  complete: function() {
    //called when complete
  },

  success: function() {
    //called when successful
 },

  error: function() {
    //called when there is an error
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also force your data to be a json in the success function:
`data = JSON.parse(data);`