# POST array data to Express gets parsed out as JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node.js-connect

My app is Node.js using Express.

Sending this test data from my client using jQuery POST:

```
{
title: 'hello',
notes: [
{title: 'note 1'},
{title: 'note 2'}
]
```

}

And this is the result in my server code:

```
{ title: 'hello', notes: { '0': { title: 'note 1' }, '1': { title: 'note 2' } } }
```

I want to get the array of notes to insert into my DB as an Array. What am I missing?

---

As I can't add an answer myself for 8 hours (wtf?) BUT it does not really answer why Express.bodyParser does not parse JSON correctly

Ok I *can* get it to work by using:

```
JSON.stringify ( data )
```

on the client then server side using

```
JSON.parse( req.rawBody )
```

This does feel wrong and why does Express.bodyParser not parse JSON correctly?!

Comment: What code you serializing this information on the post, and what code do you use to deserialize it on the server? Ex: `JSON.stringify` etc

Comment: I'm using Node.js with Express. It parses any sent body requests using Express.bodyParser. That's all I know I'm new to Node.JS

Answer (score 18):

On your client:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  data: JSON.stringify(data),
  contentType: 'application/json',
  url: '/endpoint'
});
```

On your server:

```
console.log('POST: ',req.body);
```

The problem is jQuery mucks around with your data before sending it. If you set the right MIME type, than it leaves you free.

Comment: I had the same issue with Polymer's core-ajax. Setting the contentType to application/json resolved the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Can you post your client side jQuery code, please?  By default jQuery will send data as urlencoded, not JSON.  See [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5529685/266795) for the way to ensure jQuery sends real JSON data.

FYI the [express/connect bodyParser middleware](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/bodyParser.js) simply uses JSON.parse to parse JSON (and qs.parse to parse urlencoded data).  I don't think there are any glaring bugs in those code.  Thus I think you should double-check the data you are sending from the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this old question when looking for some other nodejs stuff.

It is a common misconception that `jQuery.ajax()` functions send data using JSON. Data is sent by jQuery as POST data and not a JSON string. As such all data types (including the numbers in your array) are sent as strings.

This means that express parses the 'array' keys as a string, and since an array can't have a string key in javascript without being an object, it is cast to an object.

Answer (score -4):

It all makes sense then; you can use `Express.bodyParser` to get a result like that, or you can use `JSON.parse` or even `eval('(' + myPostedData + ')')` to get a result object without the indexes.

With your current setup, all you need to do is:

```
for(var j = 0; j < myVariable.notes.length; j++)
{
    var currentNode = myVariable.notes[j];

    //currentode.title should be 'note 1' for j = 0, etc
}
```

Comment: I get your theory but notes.length is undefined.

Comment: Using `eval` against data submitted from the client is a gigantic security hole.  `eval` should be avoided as a general rule and is almost never necessary given the other options for introspection and metaprogramming in javascript.