# Request body is always empty on a POST

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, post, express

Client side, this is what I have happening:

```
 function saveGrades() {
  $.post("/savegrades", {classIndex: "classIndexId"});  }
```

Server side:

```
router.post('/savegrades', stormpath.loginRequired, function(req, res)  {
  console.log("Class index: " + req.body.classIndex);
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send(200);
});
```

My `bodyParser` settings are as follows:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

No matter what I have tried, `req.body` is empty and does not have the `classIndex`. What am I doing incorrectly? Why is the data not being posted to the server?

Edit: For the linked questions, I have gone through almost all relevant answers here and am unable to find a solution. It seems that that data is never being sent to the server whatsoever. The body is always empty when I check it with a debugger.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570747/jquery-posting-json

Comment: @AndreyPopov I was unable to resolve my issue with the answers in that question.

Comment: I will just try to link one more :) Have you seen this one (esp. Olli's response)? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529685/post-doesnt-send-data-as-json-but-as-x-www-form-urlencoded-instead

Comment: which framework are u using express or restify ?

Comment: @WasiqMuhammad express

Comment: @Antenka I have changed the code to use `$.ajax` with the settings Olli mentioned and I am still having the same situation occur.

Comment: Is it works without "stormpath.loginRequired" middleware?

Comment: @Antenka ended up having to specify the content type in the `$.post` call, no idea why it wasn't working correctly when using AJAX. Ah well, it is working now! The middleware was not an issue.

Comment: Just found an interesting article (check the "Preflighted requests" section). Looks like an explanation to your problem :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please check the code,

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

implemented well before,

```
router.post('/savegrades',
```

Based on your comment,

Can you please trying adding Trying adding mime type (content type) in client.

Comment: It is. My `app.js` file contains the bodyparser and other configuration things. The last line I have in `app.js` is `app.use('/', db)` Where db is my router (where the server code above is located).

Comment: @Shathik thank you! It is now correctly working. The client side code is now: `$.post("/savegrades', {classIndex: "classIndexId"}, 'json');`

Answer (score 1):

Try this and send data through **POSTMEN** to verify that data is actually comming then send it through function

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded bodies

app.post('/savegrades', function(req, res)  {
  console.log("Class index: " + req.body.classIndex);
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send(200);
});
```