# CORS doesn't work on ASP.NET Core 1.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, cors

I am trying to enable "*" CORS headers on application startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(opts =>
    {
        opts.Filters.Add(new AuthorizationFilterFactory());
    });

    services.AddCors(opts => opts.AddPolicy("*",
        builder => builder
          .AllowAnyHeader()
          .AllowAnyMethod()
          .AllowAnyOrigin()
          .AllowCredentials()));

    services.AddSwaggerGen();
    services.ConfigureSwaggerGen(opts =>
    {
        opts.SingleApiVersion(new Info { Version = "v1", Title = "CORS app" });
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseCors("*");
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUi();
    app.UseMiddleware(typeof(ExceptionHandlingMiddleware));
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

The headers don't show up. Tried to request my resources with Ajax from a different domain and I am getting:

> 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

Tried with JS:

```
$.post("http://example.com/some-api", JSON.stringify({"name": "hello"}));
```

Any ideas? Maybe something wrong with the order of middleware registrations?

---

**UPDATE:** Apparently this CORS library adds headers only when it identifies XHR cross-origin requests. It suddenly started working for me. Thanks everyone for your comments.

Comment: Just an idea from the back of my memory, how about you try to use [CorsPolicyBuilder class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.cors.infrastructure.corspolicybuilder)? If I remember correctly my friend used it in Core 1.0 and it solved all problems

Comment: @MaLiN2223 thanks for your comment. The builder that is used inside `AddCors` is actually CorsPolicyBuilder. What exactly do you propose?

Comment: @MaLiN2223 yes, I did. This is just a policy name. Doesn't matter how you call it. As long as it matches `app.UseCors(policyName: "*");`

Comment: Post your js request code. My guess is you aren't using the correct content type/accept header (`application/json` e.g.)

Comment: @Mardoxx I used pretty simple JS. I also was checking headers with Postman.

Comment: Does it work using Postman? What's your controller's action look like? JQuery uses `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` by default so if you are expecting json in your action it likely won't bind properly. Try with a request like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5529700/3515174

Comment: @Mardoxx totally my fault. I fixed the request and it started working for me.

Comment: @Andrei Could you please point out what you've changed to make this work? I got the same problem!

Comment: @Lobato make sure you're sending correct request. Headers may not appear if you use Postman or other HTTP Client. With the setup that you see in the question it should be working fine.

Comment: Just asked a question here (context): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45694008/cross-origin-request-blocked-missing-token-access-control-allow-headers-no?noredirect=1#comment78346197_45694008